# Can't get sofit sections to fully rejoin/overlap - okay?

Tags: roof, siding, security, soffit

My security camera is mounted under my garage's overhang (the Ethernet run originally installed by a Tech). After i installed my security camera and moved the wires around, I was having trouble getting the two pieces of soffit where the wire was initially coming through to overlap and click together. I stuck all the wires on the inside and know only a microphone and one Ethernet wire go out to the camera.

There is no real appreciable gap, but I figure these things are supposed to overlap for a reason. Is it okay as is, or do I need to get up there and keep fighting and rearranging to ensure they actually click fully together? see photos:

[image: showing attempt to close with pry tool]

[image: showing end result how i left it]

Comment: If you don't snap these together then that will leave an easy entry point for critters.  Yes, it can be a real pain to get these to join in the middle like this but it can be done.

Comment: that makes sense, i'll try again next dry warmer day. Before the wires came out in the middle so there was a gap there. In the meantime do you think its okay if i apply some white electrical tape there? When we're talking criters, you mean  rodents not bugs? like a rodent may be able to wedge his way in?

Comment: By "critters" I was specifically thinking of rodents not insects.